Automate Formula | Excel
I have quite a complex formula issue that I am trying to fix with excel, not sure if it's possible.
Basically what I want to do is the following for my total treated patients by Product  I want to do is:
Drug A:
Jan-24 = Treated Patients by Product (current month, Jan in this case) - Drops off (Jan24)
Feb-24 = Patients from Jan24 + Treated Patients by Product (from Feb) - Drops off (Feb24)
March24 = Patients from Jan24 + Patients from Feb24 + Treated Patients by Product (from March) - Drops off (March)
For April24, I want to start over again as Jan, cause the treatments are only for 3 months. So basically, on April24 would be = Current Treated Patients (April) - Drops off (April)
May24 = Patients from April 24 + Treated Patients by Product (from May) - Drops off (May24)
June24 = Patients from April24 + Patients from May24 + Treated Patients by Product (from June) - Drops off (June)
And this every 3 months, and I would like to enter a formula on the cell for Jan24 and when I drag it it just automate this process, not sure if it's possible.
Please note that I have my data as shown on the picture. Please note that I am trying to place this formula on the C52

If someone has any idea on how to do it I will appreciate a lot! I have been struggling with these for the last two weeks
The best thing that I could do was this:
=OFFSET(D36,0,MAX(0,C55-2),1,1)-OFFSET(D49,0,MAX(0,C55-2),1,1)+OFFSET(D24,0,MAX(0,C55-2),1,1)

But only did it right for Feb24, for March24 was already not working

I avoid offset(), usually lookup() or index() with match() work better, are better behaved and easily edited.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

How can the Drops Off get for a specific month?

Reducing with MOD:
=LET(
    treated_patients_by_product, $C$34:$P$37,
    months, $C$33:$P$33,
    n_months, 3,
    treatment_failure_by_product_as_percentage, $C$40:$G$43,
    treatment_failure_for_year, LAMBDA(y,
        INDEX(treatment_failure_by_product_as_percentage, , XMATCH(y, $C$39:$G$39))
    ),
    inital_totals, EXPAND(0, ROWS(treated_patients_by_product), , 0),
    net_patients_for_month, LAMBDA(accumulated, year_month,
        HSTACK(
            accumulated,
            IF(
                MOD(MONTH(year_month), n_months) = 1,
                inital_totals,
                TAKE(accumulated, , -1)
            ) +
                INDEX(treated_patients_by_product, , XMATCH(year_month, months)) *
                    (1 - treatment_failure_for_year(YEAR(year_month)))
        )
    ),
    DROP(REDUCE(inital_totals, months, net_patients_for_month), , 1)
)



Wow, thanks a lot I didnt know about the REDUCE function. And btw, it's actually a really good idea to use LET to simply it and have each parameter categorize it. Thanks, much appreciated!

See if this is the sort of thing you're looking for. The summation restarts after three months.
=LET(startCol,COLUMN($C:$C),startIndex,QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-startCol,3)*3+1,SUM(INDEX($C34:$N34,startIndex):C34)-SUM(INDEX($C46:$N46,startIndex):C46))


One thing I'm not sure of is that it looks like the treatment failure % applies to the whole of 2024. That's what I've assumed but it's not clear from your screenshot.

Yes, the treatment failure applies to the whole 2024, we only have the data yearly, so it will be apply it to the different months of 2024. Thanks a lot for your help, your formula works nicely. Thanks, much appreciated!
